# How can two SQL databases be merged into one database?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have 2 SQL Server databases. The reason is because I created an ASP.NET MVC project using "Individual User Accounts" for authentication. This created a default connection with a database that includes the following tables:

```
AspNetUserClaims, AspNetUserLogins, AspNetUsers, _MigrationHistory
```

I then went a step further and built out my own custom roles with a `RoleController`. So I also have a table for `AspNetRoles` and `AspNetUserRoles`.  Everything with this is working.

I also have another database that I built in Management Studio that is holding all of the data of my application. I am using Entity Framework to communicate with the database.

I currently reference both databases in my `web.config` connection strings.

But I would like to migrate the database from the default connection (with my AspNetUsers) into the one in Management Studio.

Is it as simple as copying the tables and putting them in my other database in Management Studio or can I copy the whole schema? Just trying to figure out the best approach here.

Comment: Is there a reason they were separate before?  If you need them separate but need convenience in your application, try linked tables instead, so a table from database A is accessible from database B.

Comment: There really is no reason they should be separate.  The only reason they are is because I went with a database first approach so I built the schema for my database in Management Studio before pulling the data into my project. Then when I created the new MVC project it created the second database "Default Connection (ProjectName)"

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-database-to-another-in-sql-server/

Comment: Do the databases have any of the same object names? If they do not, it's as simple as selecting each object into the unified database.

Comment: John Kane, I think that article might help clear some of this up.  I will look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can migrate tables from a database to a diferent one. On SSMS, just right click on a database, select Tasks -> Generate Scripts, and use the wizard to create a script with the table definition and data (optional) to be executed on the new database.